# How to switch input language with good old Cmd + Space in Sierra?

Tags: macos

It turns out that in macOS Sierra (10.12) by default you can switch between languages with Ctrl + Space while previously it was Cmd + Space which is faster to click because you can easily do it with just thumb.

My question is - is it possible to switch back to the Cmd + Space?

From what I see now it's not doable
 [image]

Comment: `command`-`shift`-`4`, `space`, `click`, to screenshot a window, by the way.

Comment: The shortcut was changed to Control plus space in El Capitan, although depending on how you update you can wind up with Command plus space transferred from an earlier version.  This change was also made in iOS 9 (for hardware keyboards), but there you can't change it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>␣</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>␣</kbd> are now used to "Show Spotlight Search" and "Show Finder search window" respectively.  You will have to change those shortcuts before you can change these.  Click on spotlight in the left pane, double click on the shortcut and key in your new combination to change it.

Here's proof that it can be done.
[image: Screenshot]

For the basic Apple instructions, see [this help article.](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25372)

Comment: Actually it was a case for quite a while, it's just that you always could (and can in Sierra as well) turn it off.

Comment: Then what's the problem?  Why do you say it's not doable?

Comment: now you can switch off Cmd for Spotlight but you'll still won't be able to enable if for switching languages

Comment: Check edited answer.

Comment: do you have Sierra? because I have turned off Spotlight and the screenshot in my question is made exactly after it.

Comment: Yes I'm running Sierra.  Just double click on where it says ⌘Space and change it!

Comment: oh gosh I'm stupid today (ha-ha quite possible be always) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Select the shortcut you want to change in Shortcuts-Input Sources, hit Enter to go to edit mode.
Now you can type the desired keyboard combination.

Answer (score -1):

I did it!

Select the row with <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> in keyboard settings and then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>